# How to add button functionality to android app? Also I don't know anything about java

Tags: java, android

I'm sorry if this is the wrong place to ask this question. I know nothing about coding and nothing else about java. But I want to edit an android app to have extra button functionalities, and I wanted it so much that I downloaded Android Studio and the apk of the app to do it myself. Problem is, now I don't know where to start with the code.

What I want to do is add a page turning functionality to the Adobe Acrobat Reader app that allows me to turn the page to the right when I press the up volume key and turns the page left when I press the down volume key when in reading mode. Where could I edit the code to add this?

Comment: There is no code in apk that you would change.

Comment: You should study Android development and develop your own reader app, it shouldn't be so hard. Or rather take an open source reader and you will be able to add your wanted button, but again, you must study Android development, no easy way :)

Comment: Are you saying that it is impossible to edit an apk to be able to do what I want? Is it possible to reprogram the volume keys to an equivalent to a simple "swipe left" and "swipe right" throughout the entire app?

Comment: @CharlieRotunda, look at CommonsWare profile, before you have second thought's about his answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can not just edit the app from `apk` file. You will need Adobe Acrobat App [source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code) to edit the app functionalities. The functionality you want is not that hard to achieve, you can create your own pdf reader app but you will need to understand the code basics first.

If you are really interested then I would suggest you to follow beginner android app development course and then [create](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lrnEINxLEik) your own pdf reader.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between an [APK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_application_package) and [source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code). An APK is an assembled application (built from source code, and usually obfuscated so you can't see or edit the code that went into making it), so no, you cannot edit it to add features.

If you have the source code for an app (and appropriate legal permissions from the app owner, if applicable) you can certainly edit it and add features, but you aren't going to get the source code for a proprietary app like Adobe Acrobat.